# How do you determine if a mailitem in outlook from access 2013 is still open

Tags: vba, outlook

need to determine if a mailitem is open.

I can't open email in modal form because users need to be able to view other emails.

right now I display mailitem.display true which causes a problem, it should be just mailitem.display but then the code will continue.

I need to have a loop that will continue while the email is still opened

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all `Application.Inspectors` windows and check their [CurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.currentitem) property which returns an Object representing the current item being displayed in the inspector.

For `Explorers` check out the `Application.Explorers` property which returns an `Explorers` collection object that contains the `Explorer` objects representing all open explorers.

```
Sub GetSelectedItems()  
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer  
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection  
 Dim MsgTxt As String  
 Dim x As Integer 

 MsgTxt = "You have selected items from: "  
 Set myOlExp = Application.Explorers.Item(1)  
 If myOlExp = "Inbox" Then  
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection  
 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count  
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & myOlSel.Item(x).SenderName & ";"  
 Next x  
 MsgBox MsgTxt  
End If 

End Sub
```